# Java multithread Leibniz series calculation outputs wrong answer but gives right answer with one thread

Tags: java, multithreading, pi

I'm trying to calculate the PI number using the Leibniz formula. When I set the number of threads to 100, it gets different outputs in different executions, but it gets the right answer whenever I set the number of threads to 1.

This exercise is just for educational purposes and I'm not going to use it in a real-world calculation. I'm sure my formula works well as you can see in

```
term = BigDecimal.ONE.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(2L * i + 1), mc);
```

Here's my full code written in Java language:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.MathContext;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.text.Bidi;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class PiCalculator {
        public static class PICal implements Runnable
        {
            public static BigDecimal floatingPoint;
            public static boolean flag = true;
            public static MathContext mc;
            private final Long number;
            private final Long iter;
            public static BigDecimal pi;
            public PICal(Long number,Long iter) {
                this.number = number;
                this.iter=iter;
            }
            public synchronized void job(BigDecimal n,boolean flag)
            {
                if(flag)
                    pi = pi.add(n);
                else
                    pi = pi.subtract(n);
            }
            @Override
            public void run() {
                BigDecimal term;
                Long i;
                boolean add = number % 2 != 1;
                for (i = number; i < iter ; i ++) {
                    term = BigDecimal.ONE.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(2L * i + 1), mc);
                    if (term.abs().compareTo(floatingPoint) < 0) {
                        if(i.equals(number))
                            flag = false;
                        return;
                    }
                    job(term, add);
                    add = !add;
                }
            }
        }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int floatingPoint = 8;
        BigDecimal base = new BigDecimal("0.1");
        PICal.floatingPoint = base.pow(floatingPoint+1);
        PICal.mc = new MathContext(floatingPoint+1);
        PICal.pi = BigDecimal.ZERO;
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        Long power = (long) Math.pow(10 ,6);
        for (int i = 0; i < 100 && PICal.flag ; i++) {
            executor.execute(new PICal(i*power,(i+1)*power));
        }
        executor.shutdown();
        try {
            executor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        System.out.println((PICal.pi.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(4))).setScale(floatingPoint, RoundingMode.FLOOR));
    }
}
```

Thanks.

The number of threads in the example is the point of the whole problem. When we change the number of threads from 1 to 100, it begins to get random values for pi. Static variable `floatingPoint` in `PICal` class indicates how many iterations it takes to calculate to the right amount of precisions. So we set it to a larger number than we want. It works for 1 thread but doesn't work for 100.

Comment: Why did you use a public static class?

Comment: adding/subtracting to/from `pi` must be synchronized **on the same** instance - since `job()` is not `static`, it is synchronized on its instance, but each thread is getting its own instance of `PICal`... change `job()` to `static`, or use a dedicated instance for synchronizing, or, even better use classes from `java.util.concurrent`

Comment: and BTW be aware of the difference between `Long` and `long`... (also note that `pow(0.1, 9)` is just `1E-9`, `pow(10, 6)` like `1E+6`, and `(long)` of that, just `1_000_000L` [easier to read IMHO])